# Django/piston + Silverlight, PUT/DELETE?

Tags: django, silverlight, rest, django-piston

I am working on a Silverlight project that uses Django on the server using piston for the REST API. I understand that Silverlight doesn't support the PUT and DELETE http verbs. Is there another way i can pass these kinds of commands to piston?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight 3 does support PUT and DELETE if you use client networking stack. For details see: [How to: Specify Browser or Client HTTP Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(VS.95).aspx)

Comment: ok so i got further than before by registering the clienthttp prefix, but now i'm getting a security error. i assumed this was a problem with crossdomain.xml, so i added <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>, but i'm still getting the security error. is there something else i need to do to allow PUT and DELETE?

Comment: i also just added a clientaccesspolicy.xml file, and nothing changed :(

Comment: eh, decided to switch to ASP.NET MVC + RIA Services for this project. thanks for the help anyways. i'll give ya the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the MSDN article, you need to use `Client HTTP Handling` in combination with a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file that allows `PUT` and `DELETE`.

In there you have to set the `http-methods` attribute in the `allow-from` element; I set it to `*` to allow all HTTP verbs:

```
<allow-from http-request-headers="*" http-methods="*">
```

For an example of a very lenient `clientaccesspolicy.xml` look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622076/856403).