# Silverlight: HTTP DELETE and PUT methods with RestSharp

Tags: silverlight, rest, silverlight-4.0, restsharp, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I wanted to access an internal REST API from Silverlight, but it turns out that I am not allowed to use POST or DELETE as the HTTP method for my request.

Doing so always resulted in a `SecurityException`.

What is the recommended way to use REST apis with Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SecurityException probably means the API doesn't have the proper clientaccesspolicy.xml file in place. Here's an example of a *very* lenient one that allows all HTTP methods and headers. We have used this successfully for our API (which is popular, though I don't know how much traffic we get from Silverlight).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*" http-methods="*">
        <domain uri="http://*" />
        <domain uri="https://*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true" />
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

This needs to be placed in a clientaccesspolicy.xml file at the root of the domain the API you are trying to use is on.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about the `http-methods` attribute. Thanks, this makes `X-HTTP-Method-Override` unnecessary for me then.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I came up with is setting in `RestSharp` the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header, and just send POST request.

This might also be useful if you can just modify the client code, but the server has an unusuable `clientaccesspolicy.xml`.

In my API class I use this code

```
if (request.Method == Method.PUT || request.Method == Method.DELETE)
{
    request.AddHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", request.Method.ToString());
    request.Method = Method.POST;
}
```